# Preseve line breaks from textarea in Rails controller submitted with submit_to_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split, textarea

I can't believe there isn't a standard way of doing this, but I'm submitting content from a textarea to a Rails controller, and it doesn't seem to preserve the line breaks (of any form).

Here is my view code:

```
f.text_area :keywords, :cols => 50, :rows => 10

submit_to_remote 'button',  "#{t "add_keywords"}", 
     :html => {:id => 'add_keywords_button'},
     :url => { :controller=> :keywords, :action => :add_to_site },
     :escape => true,
     :loading=>"Form.Element.disable('add_keyword_button')",
     :complete=>"Form.Element.enable('add_keyword_button');",
     :update => { :success => "keywords_table_decorator", :failure => "message"
```

After submitting this goes to a controller that just needs to be able to parse out each keyword, line by line. I've tried all of the variations on the following theme:

```
@keywords = params[:site_keywords][:keywords]
puts @keywords.gsub(/\n|\r|\r\n/,'*')
```

just to see if I can get something that I can do a further split with.

I'd appreciate advice on getting this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I had this in my reset.css for all textareas:

```
white-space: normal;
```

Removing it made the problem go away.